# Error in defining sets and indexes as alias

Tags: optimization, gams-math

I'm trying to calculate the euclidean distance between some points. The coordinates of the points are denoted by x(i) and y(i), and the indices i and j are alias. For this I use the following code:

```
i "Customers";
Alias(i,j);

Parameters
x(i<)/
1        100
2        500
3        200/
y(i<)/
1        150
2        560
3        300/
;

Positive variables
d(i,j)
;

Equations
Eq1
;

Eq1..
d(i,j) =e= power(power(x(i)-x(j),2)+power(y(i)-y(j),2),1/2);
```

But an error occurs as:

*Uncontrolled set entered as constant*

which is about the line:

`d(i,j) =e= power(power(x(i)-x(j),2)+power(y(i)-y(j),2),1/2);`

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an indexed equation, you need to use, well, indices. So:

```
Equations
   Eq1(i,j)
;

Eq1(i,j)..
   d(i,j) =e= sqrt( sqr(x(i)-x(j))+sqr(y(i)-y(j)) );
```

See any GAMS model that has an equation. I also cleaned up the expression for the length (that was not correct either).